# Can makefiles by default execute unix file system commands?

Tags: makefile

I am reading makefile tutorials and I don't see how I can run unix or file system commands. This is my makefile which works right now:

```
push:
    docker build -t dataengineering/dataloader .
    docker tag dataengineering/dataloader:latest 11111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
    docker push 1111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest

deploy:
    @if [ ! "$(environment)" ]; then echo "environment must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    @if [ ! "$(target)" ]; then echo "target must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    kubectl delete deploy dataloader-$(target) -n dataengineering|| continue
    kubectl apply -f kube/$(environment)/deployment-$(target).yaml -n dataengineering
```

and I want to add `cp -r ../datastore/ .` to the beginning of push like this:

```
 push:
        cp -r ../datastore/ .
        docker build -t dataengineering/dataloader .
        docker tag dataengineering/dataloader:latest 11111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
        docker push 1111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
```

Can I do this? Where does it say I can write unix/file commads in a makefile?

Comment: Each line in a recipe is sent to the POSIX shell (sh) to be invoked.  So you can put anything into a recipe that you could type at a shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Not sure if there is any specification on limitations, but the GNU [Makefile conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html#Makefile-Conventions) mention file operation utilities throughout the docs which might be a sufficient hint that it's a feasible approach.

I.e. from the section [`Utilities in Makefiles`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command-Variables.html#Command-Variables)

> File management utilities such as ln, rm, mv, and so on, need not be referred to through variables in this way, since users don’t need to replace them with other programs.